# Какие файлы использовать?

Tags: файлы

Подскажите, какие файлы использовать при проектировании и для дальнейшей работы программы? Для примера, нужно иметь, файл в который будет записываться инф из таблицы в программе, а также считывать её, в эту же таблицу... Каким будет этот файл?.. Файл БД или какой-то другой (txt или свой формат)...

Comment: Перефразируйте вопрос, слишком размыто.

Comment: Вопрос перефразирован)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да все, как всегда, зависит от требований к проекту.
Также от языка программирования, хоть в общем-то большинство современных СУБД поддерживаются всегда, но работа с некоторыми более оптимизирована под определенную платформу.

Также советовал бы смотреть в сторону технологий, подобных db4o. Уж очень удобная система хранения, которая не требует проектировки БД. Зато имеет много основных функций СУБД.
Но пока она только развивается.

Answer (score 1):

> Ну, получается, что с файлами БД (файлы прямого доступа) легче работать, легче осуществлять поиск нужных записей, а также вставку и удаление, чем, к примеру, с текстовыми файлами (файлы последовательного доступа)..

А еще можно сделать сериализацию/десериализацию. Т.е. на пальцах я бы объяснил так: если имеется некая структура объектов, то можно каждый из них в бинарном виде положить в файл (можно в один, необязательно в несколько разных файлов). Как эти объекты есть в памяти. Для этого нужно для каждого из типов объектов нарисовать специальную функцию записи в файл и вторую функцию, которая будет считывать из файла и создавать объект. В части библиотек такая функциональность есть. Например, в [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bz744w8(v=vs.80).aspx).

А вообще, на самом деле, вопрос мне не очень нравится, т.к. слишком размыто и неясно, что конкретно хочет автор.

> Ну, получается, что с файлами БД (файлы прямого доступа)

И почему это БД - файл прямого доступа? На физическом уровне он все равно будет храниться на том же НЖМД, что и обычный, на файловой системе. Поэтому при работе с БД будет оверхед. От жуткого до незаметного, в зависимости от реализации самой БД.

Comment: Вопрос перефразирован)

Comment: <i>Для примера, нужно иметь, файл в который будет записываться инф из таблицы в программе, а также считывать её, в эту же таблицу... Каким будет этот файл?.. Файл БД, или какой-то другой (txt или свой формат)...</i><p>
Существенно лучше не стало. Тип данных какой?
В простоте можно хранить в CSV-файлах. Это таблица, в которой каждый новый элемент - новая строка, а столбцы разделены точкой с запятой. <p>Пример:
<pre>1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL! air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00</pre>

Comment: Тип данных - текстовый и числовой) Прост как бы хотелось ограничиться от пользователя, в смысле иметь файл который может прочитать только программа, но никак не пользователь... Что для этого нужно? Кодировать инф?...

Comment: Любой бинарный формат. Текстовые легко можно открыть в "блокноте" и просмотреть и даже отредактировать!

Comment: Ок) Спасибо) Будем читать про бинарный формат)

Comment: На мой взгляд текстовый формат удобнее, он более переносим для разных платформ и отлаживаться проще, хотя обычно более расточителен по памяти и времени чтения-записи. Зачем ограничивать пользователя от доступа к данным - не понимаю. В принципе можно использовать механизм прав доступа. Для контроля целостности данных можно использовать контрольные суммы.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой - [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), в некоторых языках в стандартных библиотеках реализован доступ

XML

[YAML](http://www.yaml.org/)

Бд в одном файле - [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Истина в том, что для небольших данных можно использовать текстовые файлы, а для больших и не очень маленьких - БД. С БД всегда удобнее :)

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант хранить данные в бинарном файле, что позволит  получать данные произвольно.   
Этот способ зависит от данных, которые вам надо хранить и доставать.